# FileNotFoundException (Permission denied) on Tomcat for a mounted Samba folder

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, samba

We have a strange and not reproducible issue irregularly (three times in this year so far). We have a two-node Tomcat cluster, and a webapp running on each node reads (imports) sometimes files from an external folder (a mounted SAMBA folder). And sometimes comes a problem: one of the Tomcat instance is unable to read data from the given folder, we become FileNotFoundException (Permission denied).

For example, the template for XLS export is located in that folder, and when this problem comes, the users are not able to use the XLS export functionality on that node any more.

It is the same also for such files that are brand new in that folder and neither Tomcat tried to read them before.

It seems it is not a simple permission issue, the tomcat user can reach the given folders/files, and after a Tomcat restart (only the one that has FileNotFoundException!) we have no more problem! So, I think, it is then not a concurrency issue.

Have somebody some idea how can it happen?

===============================
UPDATE:

Definitely no concurrency issue: we got the error last time in a period on Node1 when Node2 was stopped.

One more interesting thing:
I built a Quartz job that checks the folders hourly. This job runs inside our app and does the following:

```
       for (String path : getFolderPaths()) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path))
                continue;
            java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(path);
            if (!folder.canRead()) {
                // NOW WE HAVE a PROBLEM AGAIN :-(
            }
        }
```

Node1 was stopped at 00:05, started at 00:15, then Node2 was stoped at 0:25, and then the job on Node1 was active at 00:30. All the other jobs were stopped in that period and we got no HTTP request, the first thing that Node1 did after restart was this checking. And the checking was successfull for the first folder but not for the second!

Then in one hour were already both of them unsuccessfull. The both folders are brothers like /mnt/fileshare/invoices/ and /mnt/fileshare/orders/, so the problem can be with /mnt/fileshare/

Was then our first checking that caused the problem? How can it happen?

===============================
UPDATE:

I studied the results of the job that regularly checks the problematic paths. Other Tomcat instances on the same server have trouble at the same time. Other Tomcat instances on the other server sometimes at the same time, sometimes independently. Like

- Tomcat foo_A on Server A trouble with /mnt/fileshare/foo/invoices/
- Tomcat bar_A on Server A trouble with /mnt/fileshare/bar/invoices/
- Tomcat foo_B on Server B OK with /mnt/fileshare/foo/invoices/
- Tomcat bar_B on Server B OK with /mnt/fileshare/bar/invoices/

or

- Tomcat foo_A on Server A trouble with /mnt/fileshare/foo/invoices/
- Tomcat bar_A on Server A trouble with /mnt/fileshare/bar/invoices/
- Tomcat foo_B on Server B trouble with /mnt/fileshare/foo/invoices/
- Tomcat bar_B on Server B trouble with /mnt/fileshare/bar/invoices/

Comment: have you checked the samba and/or system logs on your nodes?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to that logs but I asked the administrator team to do it. They think it is the problem of Tomcat because Tomcat restart helps, but I think it is some Samba problem that Tomcat cannot tolerate without restart.